# Android - Reuse inflated View

Tags: android, layout-inflater

Following is a layout that I want to reuse

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/widget_layout"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:padding="5dip"
    android:layout_margin="2dip"
    android:background="@drawable/round_corners"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/widget_title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="New Source"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

</LinearLayout>
```

I use it in my activity onCreate method as follows

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.widget_container_layout);
    LayoutInflater inflater =  getLayoutInflater();
    HorizontalScrollView news_scroll = (HorizontalScrollView)findViewById(R.id.news_scroll);
    LinearLayout newsContainer = (LinearLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.scroll_layout, null);
    TextView widgetTitle;
    LinearLayout widget_layout;

    for(int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        widget_layout = (LinearLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.widget_layout, 
        newsContainer).findViewById(R.id.widget_layout);
        widgetTitle = (TextView)(widget_layout.getChildAt(0));
        widgetTitle.setText("New Source " + i);
    }

    news_scroll.addView(newsContainer);
}
```

So I get my Linear Layout called widget_layout added 6 times to my newsContainer Linear Layout. But the text does not reflect properly.

I expect to see 6 text boxes with text as

> New Source 0 New Source 1 New Source 2 New Source 3 New Source 4 New Source 5

But the output I get is

> New Source 5 New Source 0 New Source 0 New Source 0 New Source 0 New Source 0

Comment: where you are adding "widget_layout" in your "newsContainer"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All inflated `widget_layout`s in the `news_container` have the same ID. It looks like `findViewById` in the loop is not returning the last added widget but just some widget with that ID.
Try, instead, inflating the widget with null parent and then add it to the container.
Something like this:

```
for() {
    widget_layout = (LinearLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.widget_layout, null);
    widgetTitle...
    news_container.addView(widget_layout);
}
```

Check LinearLayout's `addView` for more info and options.